# wp_insert_post with a form

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php

$submitted = $_POST['submit'];
$post-title= $_POST['post_title'];
$post-content= $_POST['post_content'];


$new_post = array(
            'post_title' => '$post-title',
            'post_content' => '$post-content',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => $user_ID,

        );
if(isset($submitted)){
wp_insert_post($new_post);
}

?>

<form method="post" action=" "> 
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>

<textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea> 


<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="7,100"/> 

<input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

I tested it with out the form and it worked fine. but for somereason i cant seem to get it to work with the form. any ideas?

also what is supposed to go in the action for the form?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') {
    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
    $post_category = $_POST['cat'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

    $new_post = array(
          'ID' => '',
          'post_author' => $user->ID, 
          'post_category' => array($post_category),
          'post_content' => $post_content, 
          'post_title' => $post_title,
          'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    // This will redirect you to the newly created post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    wp_redirect($post->guid);
}      
?>      

<form method="post" action=""> 
    <input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&hierarchical=1'); ?>
    <textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea> 
    <input type="hidden" name="new_post" value="1"/> 
    <input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

If input with name **new_post** and value of 0 then add the post. No action needed for the form, but you should keep the PHP part on the top of the header.

Comment: i tried it on index.php and it does not work. nothing went into the database. hmmm thanks very much

Comment: I told you, keep the PHP op part, on the top of header.php file. This works 100%, I tested right now.

Comment: thanks for the help @Vlad.. i have no idea why..it's not doing it. but i will look more into it.. i did all you told me.. thanks again

Comment: i got the php part before the `get_header()` function and no result. do u think something is wrong?

Comment: Yes: if(isset($_POST['new_post']) == '1') { I edited the PHP part. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

leave the form action blank means it will flow form data from entry point of application to the current url in address bar

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
    $post_category = $_POST['cat'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    $custom1= $_POST['add_info'];
    $image_name=$_FILE['feture_image']['name']; 

    $image_url=$_FILE['feture_image']['tmp_name'];

    $new_post = array(
          'post_type' => 'news', 
          'post_content' => $post_content, 
          'post_title' => $post_title,
          'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    $post = get_post($post_id);



    add_post_meta($post_id, '_add_info_data', $custom1);    
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array($post_category), '< category_slug_name >' ); 



     $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );







}      


?>      






<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
    <input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&hierarchical=1&taxonomy=< taxonomy name >&post_type=< post_type >'); ?>
    <textarea rows="5" name="post_content" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea> 
    <input type="file" name="feture_image">
    <input type="text" name="add_info">
    <input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>   
</form>
```