# Want to replace post content with the Post title - jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html

Legalize first: I am trying to learn PHP and Javascript for Wordpress. I have looked for the answers to this question, but since I don't really understand PHP and JS that well, I couldn't find the answer - even though I may have seen it or read it.

I create a title for a custom post type in my function.php file, and afterwards I want to insert it into the body/content of the post.

I used the same function for replacing the title and the content.

The below code works in that the title of the post is replaced, but the content is not.

I thought the jQuery would do it, but maybe the content works differently, or I used the wrong process.

Can someone help me?

Here is the HTML:

```
    //Add CARS meta boxes

    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'car_meta_boxes' );
    function car_meta_boxes() {
        add_meta_box(
            'car_info',
            __( 'Car Info'),
            'car_info_div',
            'cars'
        );
    }
    function car_info_div( $post ) {
      // Use nonce for verification
         wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'car_noncename' );

    //CARS Data Entry Fields
?>
    <div>
        <label for="car_calc_name"><?php _e("Car Name");?></label>
        <input type="text" name="car_calc_name" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'car_calc_name', true);?>" /><br>
        <label for="car_calc_color"><?php _e("Car Color");?></label>
        <input type="text" name="car_calc_color" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'car_calc_color', true);?>" /><br>
        <label for="car_calc_series"><?php _e("Car Series");?></label>
        <input type="text" name="car_calc_series" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'car_calc_series', true);?>" /><br>
        <label for="car_calc_descript"><?php _e("Car Discription");?></label>
        <input type="text" name="car_calc_descript" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'car_calc_descript', true);?>" /><br>
        <input type="button" value="Create" id="create" />
        <input type="button" value="Replace" id="replace" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Then the PHP:

```
// Cars REPLACE Button

jQuery('#replace').click(function(){
    //get the parts of the title
        var cname = jQuery('input[name="car_calc_name"]').val();
        var ccolor = jQuery('input[name="car_calc_color"]').val();
        var cseries = jQuery('input[name="car_calc_series"]').val();
        var cdescript = jQuery('input[name="car_calc_descript"]').val();


//Update title
    var title = cname + ' - ' + ccolor + ' - ' + cseries + ' - ' + cdescript;
    jQuery('input[name="post_title"]').focus().val(title);
    jQuery('input[name="post_content"]').focus().val(title);
    });
    //-->
```

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with this code.  Are you getting JavaScript Errors?  Can we see the HTML?

Comment: No Errors, just the title is not put into the content box.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok to me, but it'd help if you posted the relevant HTML too to be sure. Is the post content really stored in an `input` element though, not a `textarea` ? If that's the case, you could try `jQuery('textarea[name="post_content"]').val(title);` instead.

You don't actually need the .focus() bit in there to set the value, it'll work without that.

Comment: In your jQuery you're referencing input fields with names of post_title and post_content, but neither of them are in the HTML you posted ?

Comment: Aren't these wordpress fields? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Comment: Have you tried changing it to textarea instead of input, as in my post ? I'm pretty sure it must be related to that, that would explain why post_title would work because that is an input element, but post_content doesn't because it isn't. Look at the wordpress HTML in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321914/wp-insert-post-with-a-form for instance.  You also could try just  jQuery('[name="post_content"]').val(title);

Comment: Sorry - yes I did try replacing my original line with jQuery('textarea[name="post_content"]').val(title); - but it did nothing.